# Display multiple message while validation mobile number using custom annotation

Tags: java, spring

I have used below custom annotation for validating contact number

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ContactNumberValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ContactNumberConstraint {
    String message() default "Invalid phone number";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class ContactNumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ContactNumberConstraint, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ContactNumberConstraint contactNumber) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String contactField, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        return contactField != null && contactField.matches("[0-9]+") && (contactField.length() > 8) && (contactField.length() < 14);
    }

}
```

In this class we have added validation logic. But in one condition we have puted 3 condition in single line. If above 3 condition meets then it will display 
"Invalid phone number"

This is showing only one message every time if mobile is invalid.
But if I want to validate mobile in below steps and display different different message.

I want to separate above single condition in multiple way so that it would be more user specific.

1. If mobile number field is null then it should display "Mobile number field is not empty"
2. If mobile number passed as String then it should display "Mobile number should be in string"
3. If mobile number length is less then 9 then it should display "Mobile number more then 9 digit"

Comment: Why the custom validation? Adding `@NotNull`, `@Pattern("[0-9]+")` and `@Size(min = 9, max=14)` should yield exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are correct. I am asking just for knowledge. So that I can implement for other validation.